# How to fix: No file output from remote wmic called via Python WMI module through win32_Process.Create

Tags: python, wmi, wmic

I'm attempting to execute WMIC on a remote host through the WMI module via Win32_Process.Create() function and save the output on said remote host via /output, more or > but neither of these is generating the expected output.  Instead, I am receiving empty files.

I have tried using /output, more and > to achieve proper output but the resultant files are always blank. I know that I am creating processes with expected output otherwise because I have tried using 'ipconfig >' into a file on the remote host and it gives the expected output with network configuration data, it is only WMIC that is giving me trouble.  I have also tried removing the 'cmd.exe /c' portion and just running directly with wmic.exe with no luck as well as specifying the exact executable location.

I've also tried using /Output:FILENAME alone and /Output:STDOUT with the redirector (>) to a file.  None seem to work properly.

```py
import wmi
session = wmi.WMI(computer="192.168.8.132", user="testing", password="testing")
process_startup = session.Win32_ProcessStartup.new()
command = r"wmic.exe /output:C:\Users\testing\WMIUsers0.txt /namespace:\\root\cimv2 UserAccount get * /value"
process_id, return_value = session.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine=command, ProcessStartupInformation=process_startup)
print("Process Executed: "+command)
print("Process ID: "+str(process_id)+" , Return Value (0 = Success): "+str(return_value)+"\n")
```

The above code generates an empty file on the host at the expected location rather than the actual WMI returned data.  I copy pasted the 'command' given above into the remote host and it works as expected for stdout as well as generating the data within the file.

This is only an approximation of my code but represents the issue well - what do I have to modify to have actual results populate in the destination file rather than a blank file when running remotely over the WMI module?

edit:  Using ProcessHacker on the target, I can see my process started with the parameters 'cmd.exe /c wmic /output:"C:\Users\testing\WMIUsers0.txt" /namespace:\root\cimv2 UserAccount get * /value' - If I copy paste this into a separate cmd window, it works as expected and generates the file but when I run it remotely, even though it has the proper parameters, it generates an empty file.  I am going insane trying to figure out why this isn't working..

Edit2: I've tried to many different variations utilizing subprocess.call, check_output and other things and am having no luck trying to do this in Python.  Today is not my day.

Edit3:  Decided to just use subprocess.getoutput and store the data locally because getting it to execute remotely was driving me insane - No idea why it won't work after inspecting what was executing - same exact cmdline window parameters but one generates blank file, other was dataful.  Crazy, has to be some functionality of the WMI module preventing proper transfer..or something...no idea.

Comment: If it's `wmic`, isn't it better to just do regular WMI queries?

Comment: That is a potential option but I would like to get this working for the sake of consistency really - and because it's been bothering my all day at this point.